# Regular expression syntax to match first segment only

Tags: regex, match, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have number of URLs where I need to match first segment without "/" with Regex

This segment can be either xx or xx-xx.

I've tried to do it with lookahead and lookbehind but sometimes in the URL I have another 2 letter segment. (/ts/; /ca/)  I don't want /ts; /ca/ them to match.
I only want first segment in my Regex. Any suggestions? Thanks.

https://regex101.com/r/Qy3nyI/1

```
(?<=\/)\w{2}(-\w{2})?(?=\/)
```

Test urls:

```
/en/home.aspx
/en-gb/ts/tc/home.aspx
/en-gb/home.aspx
/en-de/home.aspx
/de-de/home.aspx
/en/home.aspx
/en-fb/afspfas.aspx
/en-gb/ts/ca/anotherPage.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a starting `^` anchor to the initial lookbehind in your current regex pattern:

```
(?<=^/)\w{2}(-\w{2})?(?=/)
    ^^ change is here
```

Updated demo:

### Demo

This pattern says to:

```
(?<=^/)         lookbehind and assert that what precedes is a leading /
\w{2}(-\w{2})?  then match the country abbreviation text
(?=/)           lookahead and assert that what follows is another /
```

Comment: Thanks. I swear to god I tried that :-).it is OK. 

can you give example if I grab full URI? (with domain)